# matplotlib Text size [left, bottom, width, height]

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I wonder how to calculate exactly the size of a matplotlib.Text.

```
# this gives the position of the center of the text in the figure
xy = text.get_position()
# text size like in axes.get_position()
[left, bottom, width, height] = text.???
```

For the text it might be more complicated because all depends on the font, fontsize etc. I was thinking that I can use `text.get_bbox_patch()` or `text.get_clip_box()` but both return None

Comment: Did you call `text.get_bbox_path()` and `text.get_clip_box()` after you have drawn the figure? I think the size of a `matplotlib.Text` instance can only be determined after it has been drawn!

Comment: @DavidZwicker I believe you are correct about the size only being known once it is drawn.  This is the reason that `tight_layout` needs two passes.

Comment: Yes I definitely called both text.get_bbox_path() and text.get_clip_box() after drawing the figure. None is returned ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

text.get_window_extent() is the way to go.

for some reasons text.get_bbox_path() is always returning None